# How many visitors can my dedicated server handle at once?

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cdn, bandwidth

I have a dedicated server with these specs:

- Processor: Intel Core i5 3.40GHz (3570)
- Memory: 2 x 4GB DDR3
- Hard Disk: 2 x 1TB (Raid-1)
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Web 64bit Edition
- 30Mbps bandwidth

The server side system will be using Laravel 5.1.

How many visitors can the server handle at once serving mainly json content to mobile app, given that the domain has been boost by CDN like Cloudflare? Of course there are many other factors can affect it, however I just want to get an estimated number to have a concept & idea on how many visitors can the server handle at once before they can feel the slowness of respond from the server or the server is overloaded.

Comment: Benchmark it and see.

Comment: You can't get an accurate estimate, you have to benchmark it. There are many factors that play a role here, and your app's way of working is crucial here.

Comment: @JonStirling Please suggest how? Any tools to use?

Comment: @user1995781 That's probably a question best left to one of the other stackexchange sites like ServerFault imo.

Comment: @Mjh No need accurate. All I need is to get a concept and idea in general.

Comment: @user1995781 If accuracy is not an issue. You will be able to cope with at least 1 request per second from the information provided. Beyond that, you'll need to do your own tests.

Comment: Google for `wrk`, `siege` or `ab` tools and hit your server. That's the only way to accurately determine how many requests it can serve. It's unknown at this point what the bandwith of your RAM is, how many IOPS it can perform, what's the bandwith and IOPS number of your RAID array or whether your app will be I/O or CPU bound. You can hit problems with concurrent users, which implies that your app heavily depends on the HTTP server and its means of handling connected people. As you can see, many things play a role and as @JonStirling suggested - benchmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I just want to get an estimated number to have a concept & idea on how many visitors can the server handle at once before they can feel the slowness of responses from the server or the server is overloaded.

This really depends on your code/application and you would need to do calculations for your specific application, size of the JSON that is being served, processing that is required for each request, etc.  If you are unsure of how the code works, you can use a profiling tool or do a quick simulation for rough numbers.

In case of most likely bottlenecks:

- CPU: find out how much CPU time the server would consume in idle and when 100 or 1000 calls are made (for rough estimates).  You can simulate calls fairly easy using javascript in Chrome Console.  Extrapolate to see when the CPU will reach to 60% and 90% utilization.
- Bandwidth: while doing the above check the inbound and outbound total traffic on the network interface.
- Memory: if the system runs out of RAM then it will start swapping on HD which will be slow. Check RAM usage before, at peak and after the above checks.

**As an alternate**

You can also use a performance profiling service like loadimpact.com which gives you more specific measures on what level of "slowness" aka latency or what type of errors the users will be getting under various loads.  This requires you to already have something up and running.

=============

In practice, I would suggest using a scalable HW solution like Apigee, AWS or Azure so you can start and launch your app with one backend server and then easily scale the backend if you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, bandwidth isn't the major issue? Given that 30Mbps bandwidth, if every users are browsing at the speed of 2G, it will be capable of serving only 70 users at the same time?

Comment: No, if you have 30 megabits per second and if your content is 4 KB, then you will be able to serve 937.5 requests per second. It's irrelevant if someone's bandwith is 64k or 4G if the content you are transferring is less than that.

Comment: The question is about the server's bottleneck not the user's bottleneck.  If a user is using a slow 2G mobile, the slowness from their end is not because of the limits of the server but because of the user's connection.  Changes to the server HW is not going to make any difference for that user.

Comment: If you have a 30Mbps line, but you are serving large JSONs (i.e. 1MB each - I have seen people do it, not the smartest way to do it) then you may need to watch for the bandwidth as well.

Comment: @Mjh Thanks for your comment. Now I get the sense that my server only capable of serving less than thousand people at the same time. Given that the average content should be more than 4KB, plus it would include some images as well (as not everything will be cached by CDN). Also, some logic of execution, it is possible way below thousand people.

Comment: @YasharF Thanks for your suggestion. I guess I would look into those cloud service. Which one would you suggest or the cheapest one?

Comment: >> Which one would you suggest or the cheapest one?  Apigee and Heroku both have free starter tiers for NodeJS based API servers.  I'm not sure about hosting for Laravel thou.